# How to tell if two shapes are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I've learned the definition of homeomorphism as a continuous bijection that has a continuous inverse. However, quite often in the textbooks there is no mentions of specific maps, only a hand-wavy comment along the line of "this set is homeomorphic/not homeomorphic to that set." This makes it hard to analyze new cases when I encounter them.

For example, I need to see if the 2-complex below in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to the ball $B^2$. Any comment on how to check the conditions for homeomorphism by just looking at the shapes?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often easier to show that two spaces are **not** homeomorphic rather than they are. The reason is that there are numerous topological invariants that you can use. A [topological invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property) is some property that is preserved under homeomorphisms. Most of them work only one way, meaning that if $P$ is some topological invariant and $P(X)\neq P(Y)$ then $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$. However $P(X)=P(Y)$ does not imply that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. The simpliest example of such invariant is 
$$P(X)=\text{cardinality of }X$$

This invariant however does not work in your case since both your space and $B^2$ have cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. So we have to look elsewhere. Try

$$P(X)=\text{cardinality of }Cut(X)$$

where $Cut(X)$ is the set of all [cut-points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point) of $X$.

You can easily verify that $B^2$ has no cut-points. However your space has 1 cut-point: one of the vertices. And so they are not homeomorphic.